# Is there a way to read live SMART readings from a server and report on a different computer?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, smart

I have a server located in an awkward place in my house and i would like to know if there is a software which can report SMART statistics but to another computer.
I know there's existing software like speedfan and HDDTune but neither posses the ability to actually send live SMART stats to another machine on the network.
Basically i have a screen screwed into my wall which reports various stats such as lighting and heating. I would now like it to display my a live feed of my server's SMART stats. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### I would now like it to display my a live feed of my server's SMART stats

You may be able to achieve this using [smartd](https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/smartmontools/smartd.8.in) (part of [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/)):

> smartd is a daemon that monitors the Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology (SMART) system built into most ATA/SATA and SCSI/SAS hard drives and solid-state drives.

...

> In addition to logging to a file, smartd can also be configured to send email warnings if problems are detected.

Source [smartd](https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/smartmontools/smartd.8.in)

You may be able to do sometting with either the logfile or the email to generate a live feed.

[smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/) (and [smartd](https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/smartmontools/smartd.8.in)) is available for a variety of operating systems:

> It should run on any modern Darwin (Mac OS X), Linux, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, Solaris, OS/2, Cygwin, QNX, eComStation or Windows system.

Source [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/)